# How to make payload response return data into different format?

Tags: javascript, api

I need to change the structure of the payload response from the REST call on the frontend. Right now the api returns the data in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "row": [
      {
        "name": "Desc",
        "value": "7777 - Florida Hurricane"
      },
      {
        "name": "DSTR_NR",
        "value": "7777"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "row": [
      {
        "name": "Desc",
        "value": "7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)"
      },
      {
        "name": "DSTR_NR",
        "value": "7172"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is what I have so far but it does not give me the data in the proper format:

```
    let result = payload.reduce(function(res, obj) {
      let temp = obj.row.map(function(o) {
        return Object.assign({}, o);
      });
      return res.concat(temp);
    },[])
    return result;

// instead, this returns the data in the following way:
{name: "Desc", value: "7777 - Florida Hurricane"}
{name: "DSTR_NR", value: "7777"}
```

How can I make the payload response structure into the following desired format?

```
{name: "7777 - Florida Hurricane", value: "7777"}
{name: "7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)", value: "7172"}
```

for *name*, I only want the value for **Desc** and

for *value*, I only want the value for **DSTR_NR**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what you're looking for:

```js
const getDesiredFormat = response => response.map(data => {
    const row = data['row']
    return {
        name: row[0].value,
        value: row[1].value
    }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy.

Here you go..

```js
var data = [
  {
    "row": [
      {
        "name": "Desc",
        "value": "7777 - Florida Hurricane"
      },
      {
        "name": "DSTR_NR",
        "value": "7777"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "row": [
      {
        "name": "Desc",
        "value": "7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)"
      },
      {
        "name": "DSTR_NR",
        "value": "7172"
      }
    ]
  }
].reduce((arr, value)=>{
  var row = value.row;
  arr.push({name:row.find(x=> x.name =="Desc").value, value:row.find(x=> x.name =="DSTR_NR").value})
  
  return arr
},[])

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use map

```js
var data = [{
    "row": [{
        "name": "Desc",
        "value": "7777 - Florida Hurricane"
      },
      {
        "name": "DSTR_NR",
        "value": "7777"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "row": [{
        "name": "Desc",
        "value": "7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)"
      },
      {
        "name": "DSTR_NR",
        "value": "7172"
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(data.map(i => {
  if (i.row.length) {
    var val1 = i.row.find(f => f.name.toLowerCase() === "desc");
    var val2 = i.row.find(f => f.name.toLowerCase() === "dstr_nr");
    if (val1 && val2) {
      return {
        name: val1.value,
        value: val2.value
      };
    }
  }

}))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should handle your problem

```
result = data.reduce(function(res, obj) {
      let temp = obj.row.reduce(function(tempObj, element) {
       if(element.name === "Desc"){tempObj.name = element.value}
       else tempObj.value = element.value
       return tempObj
      }, {});
      return res.concat(temp);
    },[])
```